# Sticky header after some scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, affix

okay here's an example of what i am trying to ask,
the nav bar of [usatoday](http://www.usatoday.com).

I'm using bootstrap affix. here's my code

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="header-1">
    <h1>this is some logo</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="header-2">
    <h3>this is some heading</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content" style="height:2500px;">
</div>
<div class="footer">
    this is a footer
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$('.header-2').affix({
});
```

how can I make the div `header-2` to be fixed on the top, (when there is some scrolling and the div `header-2` just reach the top position) as of the site I've mentioned earlier?

I would love to see the `header-1` and `header-2`, but some scrolling should hide `header-1` and stick `header-2` to the top most.

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a div stick to the top of the screen once it's been scrolled to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216114/how-can-i-make-a-div-stick-to-the-top-of-the-screen-once-its-been-scrolled-to)

Comment: sticky header creation with help of jquery and css. http://www.kvcodes.com/2017/03/jquery-simple-sticky-header-on-scroll/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See this [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johnantoc/G45QM/)

you can check the position of the slider and add class accordingly

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if( $(window).scrollTop() > $('#header-2').offset().top && !($('#header-2').hasClass('posi'))){
      $('#header-2').addClass('posi');
    } else if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0){
      $('#header-2').removeClass('posi');
    }
});
```

Comment: thankyou. I was looking forward to solve this entirely with BS. :)

Comment: does this not cause some scroll bottleneck?

Comment: Any scroll event listener causes a bottleneck, that's why you should always throttle or debounce those listeners.

Comment: is it possible that header-2 is invisible while header-1 is visible, after scrolling 500px of browser window header-2 will be visible?

Answer (score 4):

use jquery look at this example
http://jsfiddle.net/5n5MA/2/

```
var fixmeTop = $('.fixme').offset().top; // Get initial position
$(window).scroll(function() {            // Assign scroll event listener
var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop(); // Get current position
if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop) { // Make it fixed if you've scrolled to it
    $('.fixme').css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: '0',
        left: '0'
    });
} else {                       // Make it static if you scroll above
    $('.fixme').css({
        position: 'static'
    });
}
```

});

Comment: its helpful but i was looking for a bootstrap specific answer. thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrapped answer using `Bootstrap.affix()`

```
$('.header-2').affix({
        offset: {
                 top: function () {
                      return (this.top = $(".header-2").offset().top);
                }
        }
});
```

This also needs CSS for the fixed positioning (see the [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix)).

> The affix plugin toggles between three classes, each representing a
>   particular state: .affix, .affix-top, and .affix-bottom. You must
>   provide the styles for these classes yourself (independent of this
>   plugin) to handle the actual positions.

```
.header-2.affix {
   top: 0;
}
```

Working example at Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/S03RlcT0z0

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
  .header {
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    position:fixed;
}
</style>
```

I'm sorry didnt look at your problem carefully.

This may helps you [Issue with Fixed Header and Bootstrap Affix / Scrollspy - Not jumping to correct location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701360/issue-with-fixed-header-and-bootstrap-affix-scrollspy-not-jumping-to-correct)

Comment: I would love to see the `header-1` and `header-2`, but some scrolling should hide `header-1` and stick `header-2` on the top most.

Comment: @John try look something like this.. if i'm not mistaken with your problem... are you insists doing this with bootstrap only? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216114/how-can-i-make-a-div-stick-to-the-top-of-the-screen-once-its-been-scrolled-to

Comment: well there's affix already on bootstrap, i would be happy if the job get done just using BS. why need to put the browser on trouble plus serving another script if its already there on BS? !!

Comment: I upvoted you because you deserve it :) 
Dont rely too much on BS, yes they are good, but they will make you lazy like me :D

Comment: well thanks dude, will take your suggestion in consideration. ;)